# Searching through list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm pretty new to python, and I'm stuck on a loop/list problem. I have two lists and want to search through the lists to find matching elements and add an item from that list to a new list.

Here's my code:

```
newList = []
elements = [["Wood", "elem1"], ["Stone", "elem2"], ["Concrete", "elem3"]]
nameNum = [["Wood", "2316"], ["Concrete", "3360"], ["Stone", "2785"]]
```

The lists can be longer and not always the same length, but just using 3 examples.
What I actually need is `newList = ["2316", "2785", "3360"]`.

Comment: FYI, `added[i] == list2[i][0]`

Comment: yeah im dumb this whole post is just dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elements = [["Wood", "elem1"], ["Stone", "elem2"], ["Concrete", "elem3"]]
nameNum = [["Wood", "2316"], ["Concrete", "3360"], ["Stone", "2785"]]
new_list =[]
for element in elements:
  for num in nameNum:
    if num[0] in element:
      new_list.append(num[1])
      break
print(new_list)
```

Looping 2 times in an nested list to extract first the element from ***elements***, then second loop to extract value from ***nameNum***

Comment: In the future you can use dictionaries to store key and values in the same array

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna import the values from a text file, but ill look into using dictionaries.

Comment: Please make your answer self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

from what I understand you want to build a new list from `list2` nested elements if the first element from the inner lists is in the `list1` in one of the nested lists on the first position:

```
list1 = [["a", 1], ["b", 2], ["c", 3]]
list2 = [["a", 1], ["c", 3], ["b", 2]]

added = {e[0] for e in list1}

new_list = [e[1] for e in list2 if e[0] in added]

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 2]
```

---

**after your edit**

you can use:

```
d = {e[0]: i for i, e in enumerate(elements)}
p = sorted([e for e in  nameNum if e[0] in d], key= lambda x: d[x[0]])
newList = [s for _, s in p]
print(newList)
```

output:

```
['2316', '2785', '3360']
```

Comment: thank you. seems like my question was poorly written. The lists aren't always the same length, and don't always have the same elements. it's a horrible example actually.. note even what i needed. figured I'd rewrite before posting nut that was a terrible idea

My actual code is:
elements = [["Wood", "elem1"], ["Stone", "elem2"], ["Concrete", "elem3",]]

nameNum= [["Wood", "2316"], ["Concrete", "3360"], ["Stone", "2785"]]

newList should be: ["2312", "2785", "3060"]

Maybe I should make a new post.. sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @imdumbplshelp do you meant the new list should be : `["2316", "2785", "3060"]` ?

Comment: @imdumbplshelp check now my answer

Comment: it doesn't work if element list is longer than nameNum, also I don't know enough python to understand it, but thanks anyways